# CSS align multiple divs

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble correctly aligning multiple divs on my page.

I want this:

```
[-----HEADER-----]
[DIV1][DIV2][DIV3]
[---SUBCONTENT---]
```

where div 1, div2 and div3 are placed in a parent div called "navigation", and "navigation" and "subcontent" are both placed in a parent div called "content".

Unfortunately, I get this:

```
[-----HEADER-----]
[DIV1][DIV2][DIV3][---SUBCONTENT---]
```

So basically my question is, how can I get another div below my 3 horizontal divs?

My code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #header { background-color: #8AB0B0; }
    #div-1 { float: left; }
    #div-2 { float: left; }
    #div-3 { float: left; }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
    <h1>Some line of text</h1>
</div>

<div id="content">

    <div id="navigation">

        <div id="div-1">div 1</div>
        <div id="div-2">div 2</div>
        <div id="div-3">div 3</div>

    </div>

    <div id="subcontent">
        Some text here
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this use `clear:both`

```css
 #header {
     background-color: #8AB0B0;
 }
 #div-1 {
     background:green;
     float: left;
 }
 #div-2 {
      background:red;
     float: left;
 }
 #div-3 {
      background:blue;
     float: left;
 }
#subcontent{
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
     <h1>Some line of text</h1>

</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="navigation">
        <div id="div-1">div 1</div>
        <div id="div-2">div 2</div>
        <div id="div-3">div 3</div>
    </div>
    <div id="subcontent">Some text here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

TRy this : i made width 33% of each div - n

```css
#header { background-color: #8AB0B0; }
#div-1,#div-2,#div-3 { float: left;width:33% }
#subcontent{float: left;width:100%}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <h1>Some line of text</h1>
</div>

<div id="content">

    <div id="navigation">

        <div id="div-1">div 1</div>
        <div id="div-2">div 2</div>
        <div id="div-3">div 3</div>

    </div>

    <div id="subcontent">
        Some text here
    </div>

</div>
```